# Galilei algebra has a simple subalgebra?

Tags: lie-algebras

The Galilei algebra has the following generators $$J_i = \epsilon_{ijk}x^j \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}, \qquad P_i = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \qquad K_i = t\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \qquad H = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}$$ The commutators are given by

$\begin{alignat}{2}
&[J_i, J_j] = \epsilon_{ijk}J_k \qquad \qquad  &&[J_i,P_j] = -\epsilon_{ijk}P_k\\
&[J_i, K_j] = -\epsilon_{ijk}K_k \qquad \qquad  &&[J_i,H] = 0\\
&[P_i, H] = 0 \qquad \qquad  &&[P_i,P_j] = 0\\
&[K_i, H] = -P_i \qquad \qquad  &&[K_i,K_j] = 0\\
&[P_i, K_j] = 0
\end{alignat}$

I'm convinced that there is no simple subalgebra of this algebra, but my course notes say otherwise. I know that there is a solvable subalgebra (namely generated by $\{K_i, P_i, H\}$), but I don't seem to see the simple algebra.

Thanks!

Comment: So the subalgebra generated by $\{J_i\}$ is the simple subalgebra...

Comment: See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29720/what-is-the-lie-algebra-of-the-galilean-group-and-what-is-the-structure-of-it). The antisymmetric matrices form the orthogonal Lie algebra, which is simple.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give a further reference with more details, so that the question is not only answered in the comments. There is an article
[On the Classification of Subalgebras of the Galilei
Algebras](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiV5tS9tNP8AhVrgP0HHb9-D_sQFnoECBAQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tandfonline.com%2Fdoi%2Fpdf%2F10.2991%2Fjnmp.1995.2.3-4.5&usg=AOvVaw3B9O6i-jZ2diH2rNf9oOkr) by Leonid Barannyk, published $2013$ in the Journal of Nonlinear Mathematical Physics. It gives much more details on the subalgebras.

Furthermore there is a post at physics stackexchange called
[What is the Lie algebra of the Galilean group and what is the structure of it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29720/what-is-the-lie-algebra-of-the-galilean-group-and-what-is-the-structure-of-it) It has an answer and several comments. In particular it is pointed out that the rotations form a simple Lie subalgebra (the orthogonal Lie algebra).